# how to monitor server sockets in Jetty

Tags: jetty, dropwizard, serversocket, monitor

I was wondering if it is possible to retrieve all open Server socket in Jetty server (I use dropwizard with Jetty) and inspect their states? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Jetty Server Dump (not java heap dump!) can show them.

https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-dump-tool.html

Also, be sure you turn on detailed dump in the threadpool
(only available if using Jetty default `QueuedThreadPool`)

```java
QueuedThreadPool.setDetailedDump(true);
```